# Hadamard-like product on infinitely differentiable functions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, taylor-series, hadamard-product

Has the following operation $*$ on formal power series $f,g$ been studied before?

$$[X^n](f*g) = n! \cdot [X^n]f \cdot [X^n]g$$

where $n$ is a nonnegative integer? This is the typical Hadamard product multiplied by $n!$.

Clearly the identity is $\exp$, our product is associative and commutative — this means infinitely differentiable functions without pole at $x=0$ form a monoid under our product.

Other straightforward identities (forgive my abuse of notation):

- $e^{ax} * e^{bx} = e^{abx}$;
- $(cf)*g  = f*(cg) = c(f*g)$;
- $\cosh x * e^{ix} = \cos x$; and
- If $c_n = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(0)}{f^{(n)}(0)}$, then the exponential generating function $\mathrm{EG}(c_n; - ) * f = f'$.

Comment: note that in general this series is not convergent, even with analytic functions, e.g. $f=g=\frac{1}{1-x}$ gives $(f*g)(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n!x^n$. Maybe you want to consider it as an operation for formal power series.

Comment: I was thinking of that example, I guess I didn't know the name "formal power series". Will make the edit, thank you!

Comment: Dividing the coefficients of a series by $n!$ is the [Borel transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation#Definition) $\mathcal{B}$. Your product is $f * g = \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{B}^{-1}(f) \cdot \mathcal{B}^{-1}(g))$ where I wrote the usual Hadamard product as $\cdot$. So all the properties of the Hadamard product translate to yours via $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}^{-1}$.